# What polynomial with real coefficients generates all polynomials with real coefficients that satisfies $f(2+i)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What polynomial with real coefficients generates all polynomials with real coefficients that satisfies $f(2+i)=0$?

Obviously, the polynomial $f(x)=x-2-i$ satisfies the constraint but does not have real coefficients. So I need to find the product of that polynomial that does have real coefficients.

Comment: If $2+i$ is a root then $2-i$ is also a root. Try $(x-2-i)(x-2+i)=x^2-4x+5$.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer, but I don't see why is $2-i$ is necessarily also a root. It's a root after you multiply by $x-2+i$, but otherwise I don't see why. thanks!

Comment: If $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$, with $a_n$ real. Then conjugating the equation $0=f(2+i)$ we get $0=\overline{0}=\overline{f(2+i)}=\sum \overline{a_n}(\overline{2+i})^n=\sum a_n(2-i)^n=f(2-i)$.

Comment: One way of looking at it is that $x-2-i$ is the conjugate of $x-2+i$, so that their product is Real as the length of the general complex number $x-2-i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with $(x-2-i)(x-2+i)=x^2 -2x+ix -2x+4-2i -ix+2i+1 =x^2-4x+5$.

In general, as Alamos pointed out, if $f(x+iy)=0$, then $f(x-iy)=0$, since the conjugate of $0$ is $0$ itself.

If you want to find all (quadratic) polynomials with $-2+i$ as a root, you need any other root $a+bi$ to satisfy $(-2+i)(a+bi) \in \mathbb R$ . By properties of Complex multiplication, multiplying is equivalent to scaling and rotating. So for the product $(x-(2-i))(x-a-bi)$ to be Real, we need $x-a-bi$ to rotate $(x-2-i)$ so that it lands on the Real axis. This only happens with the conjugate.

Basically, given a Complex number $z=a+ bi$, and $w=c+di$, for the product $zw$ to be Real, $w$ must have an argument that is the negative of that of $z$,since $$arg(zw)=argz+argw $$ (up to rotations), and you want $arg(zw)=0$